# Ext.define init object property on callback

Tags: extjs

My example :

```
 Ext.define('Shpak', 

     {
                name: 'Eugene',
                surname : 'Popov',
                getParam:function(){
                    console.log( this.param + '_____'  + this.surname )
                }
    }

    , function(){
        console.log('callback')
         this.param = 'default';
    });


    var bird =  Ext.create('Shpak')  

    bird.getParam()//undefined_____Popov
```

why undefined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check definition for callback function for [Ext.define](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext-method-define)

> createdFn : Function (optional) Callback to execute after the class is
>   created, the execution scope of which (this) will be the newly created
>   class itself.

**this** in *callback function* is the class and not the object.

*Callback function* is called after class is created and not the object.

Try adding init logic in the **constructor**. Check code below.

```
constructor: function(cfg) {
     this.param = 'default';
     this.initConfig(cfg);
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/n1czm24o/3/

**UPDATE:**

OR extract logic to init function

```
constructor: function(cfg) {
    this.initFields();
    this.initConfig(cfg);
},
initFields: function() {
    this.param = 'default';
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/sod1ft49/1/